# unable to get order status in sales_order_place_after event in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module, event-observer

Hello I am unable to get the order status in the observer sales_order_place_after I also tried other events like checkout_onepage_controller_success_action, checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after. Here is my code

```
<global>
<models>
  <xyz_customorderstatusmodel>
    <class>Endive_CustomOrderStatus_Model</class>
  </xyz_customorderstatusmodel>
</models>
<events>

  <checkout_submit_all_after>
    <observers>
      <xyz_CustomOrderStatus_Model_Observer>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>xyz_customorderstatusmodel/observer</class>
        <method>implementOrderStatus</method>
      </xyz_CustomOrderStatus_Model_Observer>
    </observers>
  </checkout_submit_all_after>
</events>
```

```
public function implementOrderStatus(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    $mytime = "time - " . date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
    Mage::log('in me');
    $status = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getStates();
    Mage::log('My variable : '.$mytime .' -- ' .$status);
    die;

 }
```

Comment: I post answer kindly check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace your code like this.

```
public function implementOrderStatus(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $status = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getStatus();
}
```

Comment: what is the error in my observer : https://paiza.io/projects/5wc-YEhCVOr3-YqB225yVA

Comment: Do the small "P" into your Observer function like this one : public function checkorderstatus

Comment: After updated "p', still log not generated, https://paiza.io/projects/5wc-YEhCVOr3-YqB225yVA i am updated my code

Comment: Put the log like this one : Mage::log($order->getCustomerFirstname(), null, 'orderproduct.log', true);

Comment: And also added this line : $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

Comment: Actually i have to send reminder message to customer whose order status pending more than 2 days. Just now i know about remainder not send simply by creating event-observer should be creating cron. How to setup cron for remainder. my post https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/298339/57334

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code instead of yours:

```
public function implementOrderStatus(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    $status = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getStatusLabel();
}
```

`$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getStatusLabel();` This will return Status label like (Pending, Processing etc)

`$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getStatus();` This will return Status Code(field values as in database) only like (pending, processing etc.)