# Magento 1.9 - how to send custom email if order status pending more than 2 days?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, email, automation

I have event observer for getting order status,

How can i send custom email if order status pending **more than 2 days**.

eg:

> Company Logo::
>   Dear {{customer name}}, Your order pending more than 2
>   days, any issue let us know.
>   Thank you.

Event-observer :

https://github.com/ZusZus/Order_Status_Monitor/tree/master/Order_Status_Monitor/app

Comment: you need to use Cron , event will not help you.

Using Cron you can check everyday and get collect all the list of order who has completed 2 days and still it's status is in pending mode.

so you can send email to them

Comment: Can i get more details how to use cron for order status?

Comment: Magento Code : https://inchoo.net/magento/creating-cron-script-in-magento/

setup cron at cpanel : https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-cron-job-in-cpanel-for-magento/